# graph quadratic form and find the equation of asymptotes

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics, quadratic-forms

So I had this quadratic form that need to be graphed showing both original and new axes. And I also need to find out the equation of asymptotes.

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
4(x_1)^2-12(x_1)(x_2)-(x_2)^2= 4
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

I think it would be a rotated hyperbola, but I don't know exact how to graph it. And for the asymptotes, I can't transfer the equation into the form of 
$$\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2} - \frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2} = 1$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE ! We highly encourage displaying your work so far in your questions, as well as formatting them using LaTeX (which I already did for you) ! Could you please edit your question in order to show what you have done so far ?

Comment: @Hippalectryon Thanks for telling me this, but this is really all I got so far, I need at least a hint or direction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Quoting Wikipedia :

*To rotate a figure counterclockwise around the origin by some angle $\theta$ is equivalent to replacing every point with coordinates $(x,y)$ by the point with coordinates $(X,Y)$, where* $$x=X \cos (\theta )-Y \sin (\theta )$$ $$y=X \sin (\theta )+Y \cos (\theta )$$

So, transform accordingly your equation $4x^2-12xy-y^2=4$; identify the $XY$ term and say that its coefficient is $0$. This should give you one equation for $\theta$. Solve it and replace $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ by their resulting values. The remaining should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

The asymptotes correspond to the roots of the quadratic polynomial in $x_1,x_2$, as the variables will strive to "achieve $0=4$".

By the classical formulas,

$$x_1=\frac{6\pm2\sqrt{10}}{4}x_2.$$

The rotated axis are the bisectrices.